# React Native App Crashes in release but works in development

Tags: react-native

I was working on an app by testing in the iOS simulator. Also I tested through a cable development version on Android. It was all good. However, when I build for production both iOS and Android crash on a specific place.

The only traces of error are the `adb logcat` that during/after the app crashes. I would appreciate any ideas that will help me debug the issue.

Android logs:

```
-14 01:30:05.000   773  1665 E dubaid  : [SystemHandler.cpp] onPartialWakelockReleaseMessage# Already released, lock: 143076769
06-14 01:30:07.828 14030 14030 E JankService: child Thread receive to stop
06-14 01:30:07.940   824  1054 E JankService: all data read ok
06-14 01:30:09.302   637  3672 E audio_custom: get_config_value: invalid path /proc/device-tree/audio_hw_config/hifi_info/highperform_lowpower_support.
06-14 01:30:09.313   637  3672 E audio_hw_effect: unsupported sws effect version!
06-14 01:30:09.313   637  3672 E audio_hw_effect: sws set parameter func:[8] err: [-61]
06-14 01:30:09.318 13884 13932 E ReactNativeJS: Requiring unknown module "./locale/en-GB".
06-14 01:30:09.326 13884 13932 E ReactNativeJS: Requiring unknown module "./locale/en-gb".
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: Process: my.bigwin.com, PID: 13884
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Requiring unknown module "./locale/en-GB"., stack:
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: h@2:1448
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: d@2:868
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: Dt@861:16712
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: Tt@861:17738
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: Yt@861:16801
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: n@947:1453
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: Sn@90:30120
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: Or@90:45887
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: na@90:72881
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: ra@90:73371
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: Oa@90:80972
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: Wa@90:80310
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: Ue@90:83367
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: De@90:13673
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: We@90:13846
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: receiveTouches@90:14605
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: value@28:3311
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@28:822
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: value@28:2565
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime: value@28:794
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
06-14 01:30:09.343 13884 13933 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
06-14 01:30:09.347   824  3397 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.348   824  3397 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.348   824  6429 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.349   824  6429 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.349   824  6429 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.357   824  6429 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.358   824  6429 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.362   824  6429 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.364   824  6429 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.365   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.365   773  1665 E dubaid  : [DubaiUtils.h] parseMessage# Failed to find second tag: uid=
06-14 01:30:09.366   773  1665 E dubaid  : [SystemHandler.cpp] parsePartialWakelockAcquiredMessage# Failed to parse count: lock=20712722 tag=IntentOp:.common.broadcast.BackgroundBroadcastReceiverSupport$PersistentReceiverIntentOperation count=0
06-14 01:30:09.366   773  1665 E dubaid  : [SystemHandler.cpp] onPartialWakelockAcquireMessage# Failed to parse message
06-14 01:30:09.366   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.370   773  1665 E dubaid  : [SystemHandler.cpp] onPartialWakelockReleaseMessage# Already released, lock: 20712722
06-14 01:30:09.371   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.376   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.376   773  1665 E dubaid  : [DubaiUtils.h] parseMessage# Failed to find second tag: uid=
06-14 01:30:09.376   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.376   773  1665 E dubaid  : [SystemHandler.cpp] parsePartialWakelockAcquiredMessage# Failed to parse count: lock=7945443 tag=IntentOp:.common.broadcast.BackgroundBroadcastReceiverSupport$GmsReceiverIntentOperation count=0
06-14 01:30:09.376   773  1665 E dubaid  : [SystemHandler.cpp] onPartialWakelockAcquireMessage# Failed to parse message
06-14 01:30:09.376   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.378  1231 10848 E ActivityManager: The same pid with last one, do not add dropbox and clear mLastCrashedPid. mLastAppCrashedPid==13884
06-14 01:30:09.382   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.382   773  1665 E dubaid  : [SystemHandler.cpp] onPartialWakelockReleaseMessage# Already released, lock: 7945443
06-14 01:30:09.382   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.385   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.388   659  1532 E AudioFlinger: writing blocked, write to hal costs: 70 ms
06-14 01:30:09.398   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.403   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.423   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.425   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.430   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.433   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.436   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.438   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.446   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.449   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.453   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.454   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.455   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.457   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.458  1231  1753 E InputDispatcher: channel 'b8833ec my.bigwin.com/my.bigwin.com.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-14 01:30:09.459   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.459   824  6434 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.459   824  6442 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.459   824  6442 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.459   824  6442 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.460   824  6442 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.460   824  6442 E iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
06-14 01:30:09.475  1231 25557 E         : [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0110]
06-14 01:30:09.479  2088  2781 E Hicom_PolicyCenterService: handleAppDied. null == mMultipathAppsMap
06-14 01:30:09.480  2088  2104 E HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
06-14 01:30:09.484  1231 15387 E WindowManager: win=Window{b8833ec u0 my.bigwin.com/my.bigwin.com.MainActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true
06-14 01:30:09.504  1231  1269 E libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99036 pid 13973: No such file or directory
06-14 01:30:09.507  5645  5699 E BluetoothLeScanner: updateLeScanParams win:60 ivl:600
06-14 01:30:09.511  1544  1544 E OCTTY   : [main:370] install already set to
06-14 01:30:09.511  1544  1544 E OCTTY   :
06-14 01:30:09.513  2195  2503 E powergenie_jni: FUNC: setHisiCABCInner() LINE: 60  open /dev/pri_lcd error: No such file or directory
06-14 01:30:09.513  2195  2503 E DisplayControl: Fail! set cabc mode: 1
06-14 01:30:09.515  2088  2781 E XEngineMpipControl: Invalid SubId
06-14 01:30:09.519  1544  1544 E OCTTY   : [main:370] install already set to
06-14 01:30:09.519  1544  1544 E OCTTY   :
06-14 01:30:09.520  2088  2990 E DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:my.bigwin.com/my.bigwin.com.MainActivity state:18 fg:false mUid:10275
06-14 01:30:09.522  2228  2312 E HwLauncher: SettingsEx , no such field.
06-14 01:30:09.538   661  3418 E BufferQueueProducer: [] mConsumerName == NULL!!!!!!
06-14 01:30:09.541  2393  2407 E         : [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
06-14 01:30:09.544  2195  3326 E AwareLog: SPKSchedFeature: Uid has been sent, ignore.
06-14 01:30:09.544  2088 31236 E HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
06-14 01:30:09.547  2088 31236 E HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 103
06-14 01:30:09.555  2088  2990 E DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.drawer.DrawerLauncher state:2 fg:true mUid:10087
06-14 01:30:09.555  3819  3837 E AppLifeChangeSensor:  CAWARENESS: activityResumed mAppLifeChangeCallback is null
06-14 01:30:09.558  1231  1938 E         : [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0111]
06-14 01:30:09.972  1231 10719 E NetworkStats: getIfaceStats rmnet0 type 5 failed, return qtaguid stat 190962
06-14 01:30:09.972  1231  1244 E NetworkStats: getIfaceStats rmnet0 type 4 failed, return qtaguid stat 394005
```

I see all kinds of things, but I am unable to figure out which one causes the crash.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

After all it had to do with the languages where it says `Requiring unknown module "./locale/en-GB".`

I fixed this and it was up and running.

Comment: How did you fix that?

Comment: Can you share with us how you fixed it, please?